# PowerPoint - how to connect the font size between text boxes?

Tags: powerpoint, ms-office

In PowerPoint you can choose the option "Shrink text on overflow" for text boxes. I.e. if you type more text than the box can contain, the font size is decreased.

This is the behaviour that applies to a single text box only. I now have a presentation where two separate text boxes seem to be connected. When the text flows over in the one text box, the text is resized in both text boxes.

Question: I must be missing something, but I cannot find back how this inter-connection is created. How can I reproduce this behaviour?

To fix thoughts, here's an example that I found. This is a simple presentation with a title and two text boxes.
[A simple PowerPoint presentation with two text boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6Kh.png).

In this example, the two text boxes are connected. When I add text in the left text box and cause an overflow, the fonts get resized in both text boxes as follows.
[Same presentation with text added in the left text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7P6Q.png). While text is added in the left text box, the font size decreases both in the left and the right text box. I.e. both text boxes are linked, but I cannot find how this is done.

So, here's my question: how do I configure two text boxes in Powerpoint such that "Shrink text on overflow" applies to two text boxes at the same time?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query on http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, John. Let me try that first then.

Comment: @JurgenVGorp I'll look for your post on SuperUser to follow up on this, but most likely the slides you're looking at are based on either the Comparison or Two Content layouts. Each of those has two text or content placeholders of the same size, and forcing a text overflow in one will reduce the size of text in the other.  So to get the same effect, base your slides on one of those two layouts.  Let PPT do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve. In the meantime I have asked the same question in answers.microsoft.com, as John suggested. In the meantime I have my answers, which are very similar to your answer. Let me answer my own question with reference to answers.microsoft.com, so other people can find back the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

As John Korchok suggested, this question was posted on answers.microsoft.com.

The answer is that the feature only exists in PowerPoint layouts containing 2 content placeholders: Comparison and Two Content. The solution is then to reset the slide to the standard MS format.

for sake of completeness and to not leave this question unanswered: the details and screenshots can be found in the following topic.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-how-to-connect-the-font-size-between/143ddbd3-f88b-47f2-9649-7397756869b2.